# Use principle of mathematical induction to show a function defined recursively is uniquely determined.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, recursion

I'm having difficulty with the following taken from "Elementary Number Theory And Its Applications" by Rosen section 1.1 questions.

"Use the Principal Of Mathematical Induction to show that the value at each positive integer of a function defined recursively is uniquely determined."

A Recursive Function is defined previously as:

Definition: We say the function  ***f***  is defined recursively if the value of  ***f***  at  ***1***  is specified and if a rule is provided for determining ***f(n+1)*** from ***f(n)***.

The question implies a general proof. But as far as I can gauge the only way I can be sure a recursive function is indeed uniquely determined is if I know what the actual function involved is?

e.g. a recursive function could be defined such that the RHS was fully a square root term implying 2 solutions?

Comment: You can find a prize-winning exposition on this an related matters in Leon Henkin's Monthly article [On mathematical induction.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2308975)

Comment: This is just [Dedekind's recursion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem).

Comment: What exactly is an "RHS"? Please don't have the misconception that what is on the right is a definition. Also, if $f(n+1)$ can be determined from $f(n)$, it does not matter whether there were square-roots involved in the definition, because "determined" means "has exactly one fixed value".

Comment: ok what if I define a recursive function like this: $(f(n+1))^2 = f(n) + 2n$. That appears to follow the definition but the value at each positive integer of the function is not UNIQUELY determined.

Comment: Even if you took the positive square root in this case, I don't think this particular function would satisfy the above definition of a recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $f:N\to R$,

$f':N\to R$,

$g:R\to R$,

$f(1)=f'(1)=x_1\in R$,

$f(x+1)=g(f(x))$,

$f'(x+1)=g(f'(x))$.

Note that:

$f(1)=x_1$,

$f(2)=g(x_1)$,

$ f(3)=g(g(x_1))$,

$f(4)=g(g(g(x_1)))$, ...

Similarly for $f'$.

Prove by induction that for all $x\in N$, we have $f(x)=f'(x)$.

Base case: Prove $f(1)=f'(1)$.

Inductive Step: Suppose $f(k)=f'(k)$. Prove $f(k+1)=f'(k+1)$.